# Why these "Earlier" shown in Finder's column title for one of my NFS mounts?

Tags: finder, nfs

It suddenly appears just now for one of my NFS mounts:

[image: "Earlier" appeared in Finder Columns]

Other volumes still plain old normal:

[image]

What these "Earlier" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because they're listed grouped by dates, and all your files are "old" (i.e. not modified recently).

Click the arrange icon (the one with the six squares divided by two lines) and select "None" to get rid of the header.